# Unable to start debugging on the web server.

Tags: asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2013

Ok so I've set up IIS on my laptop, I then went to visual studio and created a new test project called IISTest, right clicked the solution > properties > Web > and choose > Local IIS and created the virtual directory, message popped up saying directory was created successfully, I then open IIS to make sure its there and below is what I see - seems normal:
[image]

I then run the project and got the follow message:

Unable to start debugging on the web server. Unable to connect to the web server. Verify that the web server is running and that incoming HTTP requests are not blocked by a firewall.

I off to google I went, found this which explains the problem I'm experiencing http://saiabhilash.blogspot.com.au/2012/03/unable-to-start-debugging-on-web-server.html

When I open IIS and try to see if its running on the right hand side this is what I see, I don't get the option to select start/stop or reset:

[image]

Would anyone be able to suggest what's wrong please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You start or stop/recycle the application pool. On the left pane, Application Pools are above the Websites, the options will now appear on the right pane.

You can also run [Appcmd.exe](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772200%28v=ws.10%29.aspx), for Application Pool operations

or

Run [iisreset](https://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/003ed2fe-6339-4919-b577-6aa965994a9b.mspx?mfr=true) from the command-line, for IIS Server Wide operations